# Conversion of Sectioning Numbers in ConTeXt

Tags: sectioning, numbering, context

I would like to have the following typesetting in my ConTeXt document, but I don't master its conversion mechanism to yield it.

First part, Second part, Third part...

Chapter 1, Chapter 2, Chapter 3...

Section 1.I, Section 1.II, Section 1.III...

Subsection 1.I.a, Subsection 1.I.b, Subsection 1.I.b...

Subsubsection 1.I.a.i, Subsubsection 1.I.a.ii, Subsection 1.I.a.iii...

Thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you define a [structure conversionset](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/definestructureconversionset). The first argument is the name of
the conversion set. The second argument is the list of conversions, starting
with *part*. The last argument is a default value.

Then you apply the defined conversion set to your structure elements.

```
\definestructureconversionset
  [structure]
  [numbers, numbers, Romannumerals, characters, romannumerals] %% part, chapter, section, …
  [numbers]

\setupheads [sectionconversionset=structure]

\starttext

\startsectionlevel [title=Alpha]
  \startsectionlevel [title=Beta]
    \startsectionlevel [title=Gamma]
      \startsectionlevel [title=Delta]
      \stopsectionlevel
    \stopsectionlevel
  \stopsectionlevel
\stopsectionlevel

\stoptext
```

[image: result]

Comment: @Wondrous you can also use the traditional `\startsection`, `\startsubsection` etc rather than sectionlevels.

Comment: How to make ConTeXt print the part number in words?

Comment: @Wondrous A small nudge: At the moment at is set to `numbers` and it prints numbers and `characters` which print characters.